# AppIcon for Console Application in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, accessibility

I have created a Console Application that asks for certain rights (calendar, accessibility etc.). When prompting for rights the Application is added to the **System Settings -> Security** but without an Icon because a Console Application does not have one.

Is it possible to add an AppIcon to a Console Application somehow?

I do not need the UI. I just want the Application to have the Icon for the Security Settings.